# Find the plane which contains the lines.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Q: Find the plane which contains the lines 
$$
\langle 2,1,4\rangle + t\langle1,-2,4\rangle\text{ and }\langle2,-3,3\rangle + s\langle2,-4,8\rangle
$$

I know to get the plane I need a point and a vector normal to the plane. Since my lines are parallel if I take the cross product of the direction vectors I'll get zero. I am confused on how to get the normal vector here.

Would using the two points to get a vector, then taking the cross product of that vector and the direction of the line be the right move here?

Comment: Yes, two points, one on each line.  If the plane contains those two points, it contains the line through them. So then you would have $3$ lines, and two of them are not parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The first direction vectors are given by

$$u = <1,-2,4>$$

We also know the point $a=<2,1,4>$ (lies in first line), which lies in the plane. In order to find the second direction vector $u$ choose $t=1$ and $s=1$ determine the two points $p_1$ (on first line) and $p_2$ (on second line), then $v=p_1-p_2$. Determine the normal vector $n = u \times v$. In order to write down the plane equation use:

$$\text{Parameter form: }n \cdot (x-a) = 0  \text{ or }$$
$$\text{Vector form:} x = \mu u + \lambda v + a,$$
in which $x=<x_1,x_2,x_3>$.

Comment: n = u x v will be zero because theyre parallel

Comment: @HankManks: Thank you for your comment. Edited the answer.

Comment: Why not just use $\langle2,1,4\rangle-\langle2,-3,3\rangle$ for the second direction vector? We know that those points lie on the two lines and so this vector can’t be parallel to them.

Comment: Sure, I had realized that after posting my answer and as others already stated that I didn't want to copy that.

Answer (score 0):

take two Points, $$P_1(2;-3;3)$$ and $$P_2(2;1;4)$$ from our two lines and you can write $$[x,y,z]=[2;-3;3]+a[1;-2;4]+b[0;4;1]$$ as vector equation and $$\vec{P_1P_2}=[0;4;1]$$ as a direction vector

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using a point from each line to get a second direction vector works. This vector will be parallel to the plane and is guaranteed not to be parallel to the lines you’ve been given. The parametric equations of the lines include a point on each line, so you can just subtract those to get this vector: $\langle2,1,4\rangle-\langle2,-3,3\rangle=\langle0,4,1\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The 2 lines given have the same direction vector:(1,-2,4).

This gives you one direction vector in the plane.

The other direction vector is given by:

(2,1,4)-(2,-3,3)=(0,4,1)¡

Take the cross product of these 2 vectors to obtain the normal of the plane $\overrightarrow{n}$.

Equation of plane:

$\overrightarrow {n}\cdot(\overrightarrow {r}- (2,1,4))=0$