# Do two distinct unskewed lines uniquely determine a plane?

Tags: geometry, vectors

I thought it does and I tried to make a proof.

Here’s my proof

Let L1 and L2 be two distinct unskewed lines.
(Skewed : not intersect, not parellel)

Suppose there are two distinct planes containing both L1 and L2.

Since two planes satisfy one and only one of the followings:

1. They are same,
2. They meet on a line,
3. They don’t intersect each other,

and they can’t be case 2 or 3, they must be same.

And I also need to show that they determine at least one plane.

We can find vectors representing direction of each line L1 and L2. Let them be V1 and V2, respectively. And using cross product we can find a normal vector perpendicular to both V1 and V2. We have a point on a line and a normal vector, so we get an equation of a plane.

Is my proof right? I feel like there’s something wrong here.

Thank you for you help in advance.

Comment: It's given that the lines are _unskewed_. That means they either intersect, or are parallel. You only considered the first case.

Comment: Do you mean that I missed the second case in the proof of the existence?

Comment: Yes. If the lines are parallel, the cross-product of the direction vectors is zero, so for that case, existence needs further analysis.

Comment: Oh! Right, thanks! I should have thought about it. Hmm...

Comment: If you haven't already worked out the parallel lines case, see my comment is this thread
$$$$
$\qquad$https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460094/find-the-plane-which-contains-the-lines
$$$$

Comment: Oh, yes! I get it now! I really appreciate it :)